Replace Nth group of characters in a string split by underscores _
I want to splits a string on '_' and replace 3rd group with 'oooo'.
Is there any way to do it simply and without assuming there's exactly 5 groups?
CONCAT( SPLIT_PART(test, '_', 1)
       ,SPLIT_PART(test, '_', 2)
       ,'OOOO'
       ,SPLIT_PART(test, '_', 4)
       ,SPLIT_PART(test, '_', 5)
      )

Example:
'GjHf00_i8S7b_tst00_UL000_perce'
turns into this
'GjHf00_i8S7b_oooo_UL000_perce'

Can you add a number of example strings to your question as well as the expected output?

CONCAT_WS('', SPLIT_PART(test, '', 1), SPLIT_PART(test, '', 2), 'OOOO', SPLIT_PART(test, '', 4), SPLIT_PART(test, '_', 5))

'GjHf00_i8S7b_tst00_UL000_perce' --> 'GjHf00_i8S7b_oooo_UL000_perce'

That would work if you use concat_ws('_',split_part...) instead. Right now you're losing the underscores you're splitting on. This also assumes you always have the 5 groups.

using regex you could match ^((?:[^_]+_){2})([^_]+) and replace with $1oooo

Try matching:
^((?:[^_]+_){2})([^_]+)

and replacing with:
\1oooo

See: regex101 and fiddle

Explanation
MATCH:

^: start of string
((?:[^_]+_){2}): Capture the first two blocks to group 1
([^_]+): Capture the third block to group 2

REPLACE:

\1: Keep the start
oooo:  Replace third block with "oooo"


it's really simple and easy to change. What if I want to replace more than one like 'GjHf00_i8S7b_tst00_UL000_perce' -> 'GjHf00_i8S7b_ooooo_UL000_tax_finish'. The solution which I can only think of is one inside the other, just like Russian Dolls.

demo at db<>fiddle
select regexp_replace(test,'[^_]+','oooo',1,3)
from examples;

It's looking for substrings of 1 or more non-underscores, starting from position 1 and trying to replace the 3rd hit:

[] is a group of allowed characters
^ inside a group means it's a group you wish to exclude
_ is just the underscore
+ means you're looking for 1 or more of that

Where to start and which match to replace is handled by the rest of regexp_replace() params:

regexp_replace ( string text, pattern text, replacement text, start integer, N integer [, flags text ] ) → text
Replaces the substring that is the N'th match to the POSIX regular expression pattern, or all such matches if N is zero; see Section 9.7.3.

If you're fine with the assumption that you always have 5 groups, your idea would work as long as you swap out concat() for concat_ws(). Otherwise you'd lose the underscores you're splitting on:
select concat_ws('_',split_part(test, '_', 1)
                    ,split_part(test, '_', 2)
                    ,'oooo'
                    ,split_part(test, '_', 4)
                    ,split_part(test, '_', 5) )
from examples;


Your regexp is clearly more elegant. Edge case: empty string between separators, like ' a__xxx_c_' .

Thanks but it delegates stuff to the function so I don't think that's fair. As a regex, I'd say a portable pair of match-replace patterns is more elegant. I'm aware of the empty group thing but I figured unless OP gets more specific, I'll just keep it short.

You can find the start and end positions of the 3rd group (between the underscores) and replace it.
This takes any length of group 3 and replaces it with the required replacement value.
The first solution works only if there are 3 or more underscores, i.e. 3 or more groupings. If there are less than 3 groups, or 3 groups but no trailing underscore after the 3rd group, the solution will error (h/t @Zegarek).
A solution has been added to cater for 3 or less underscores.
SELECT
    REPLACE(
        myfield,
        SUBSTRING(
            myfield, --input
            REGEXP_INSTR(myfield,'[_]',1,2)+1, --get start position of group 3 after the 2nd underscore
            REGEXP_INSTR(myfield,'[_]',1,3) - REGEXP_INSTR(myfield,'[_]',1,2)-1  --get end position of group 3 up to but not including the 3rd underscore
        ),
        'oooo' --replace with this value
    )
FROM mytable

Using the example provided:
SELECT
    'GjHf00_i8S7b_tst00_UL000_perce' AS input,
    REPLACE(
        'GjHf00_i8S7b_tst00_UL000_perce',
        SUBSTRING(
            'GjHf00_i8S7b_tst00_UL000_perce',
            REGEXP_INSTR('GjHf00_i8S7b_tst00_UL000_perce','[_]',1,2)+1,
            REGEXP_INSTR('GjHf00_i8S7b_tst00_UL000_perce','[_]',1,3) - 
                REGEXP_INSTR('GjHf00_i8S7b_tst00_UL000_perce','[_]',1,2)-1
        ),
        'oooo'
    ) AS output

returns



input
output




GjHf00_i8S7b_tst00_UL000_perce
GjHf00_i8S7b_ooooo_UL000_perce



Include support for when there are <3 underscores:
SELECT
    myfield AS input,
    CASE
        WHEN REGEXP_COUNT(myfield,'[_]') >2 THEN 
            REPLACE(
                myfield,
                SUBSTRING(
                    myfield,
                    REGEXP_INSTR(myfield,'[_]',1,2)+1,
                    REGEXP_INSTR(myfield,'[_]',1,3) - 
                        REGEXP_INSTR(myfield,'[_]',1,2)-1
                ),
                'oooo'
            )
        WHEN REGEXP_COUNT(myfield,'[_]') =2 THEN 
            REPLACE(
                myfield ,
                SUBSTRING(
                    myfield , --input
                    REGEXP_INSTR(myfield ,'[_]',1,2)+1,
                    LENGTH(myfield )
                ),
                'oooo' --replace with this value
            )
        ELSE myfield --return the original string
    END AS output
FROM mytable

NOTE:

Example _a_b_c returns _a_oooo_c since group 1 is NULL (the content before the first underscore), group 2 is a and group 3 is b.
Example _a_b returns _a_oooo since group 1 is NULL, group 2 is a and group 3 is b.


A two-argument version of replace() isn't defined.

Thanks @Zegarek You're correct. Fixed it.

Now you're getting ERROR:  negative substring length not allowed. Here's a db<>fiddle with Erwin's test examples and mine - your code is in the 3rd box from the top. My guess is this code fails the test cases with an empty, short or otherwise malformed string.

You make a good point. My solution assumes that there are a minimum of 3 or more underscores. The OP doesn't say the minimum number of groups. I'll add a comment in my solution stating the scenario where this will and will not work.

Added handling of <3 underscores so it does not error

The best solution heavily depends on the range of possible input.
Anything goes
(Fewer or more than 5 parts, including the empty string '', empty substrings, or null.)
Regular expression with two back references:
regexp_replace(str, '(^[^_]*_[^_]*_)[^_]+(.*$)?','\1oooo\2')

... with a positive lookbehind:
regexp_replace(str, '(?<=^[^_]*_[^_]*_)[^_]+','oooo')

fiddle
split_part() is typically faster, but does not cover all corner cases.
Standard UUID literals
overlay() to replace from fixed position 15 to 19:
overlay(str, 'oooo', 15)

fiddle
Won't get faster than this.
